# How can I add two table into one?

Tags: python, pandas

I need help...I'm trying to merge tables from different sites.

I succeeded to extract each tables what I want, but I can't merge them into one..
I used 'for~~in' but failed.

[[my goal]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFygk.jpg) This image is what I'm trying to make.
I'm really new to coding and this community, sorry if the question seems bad.

Thanks for reading
Sincerely, KB

```
import pandas as pd 

ticker = '005930' #'139480'
table = pd.read_html('http://comp.fnguide.com/SVO2/ASP/SVD_Main.asp?pGB=1&gicode=A'+str(ticker)+'&cID=&MenuYn=Y&ReportGB=&NewMenuID=Y&stkGb=701')

report1 = table[10]
report2 = report1.loc[[0, 1, 3, 17]]
report2

#for tickers in ticker:
#    url=print('http://comp.fnguide.com/SVO2/ASP/SVD_Main.asp?pGB=1&gicode=A'+str(ticker)+'&cID=&MenuYn=Y&ReportGB=&NewMenuID=Y&stkGb=701')
```

Comment: if the index is the same, you can do a merge. You don't need to do a for loop. Using loops in pandas is a bad thing. There are much better ways to solve two dataframe. Search stack overflow on how to merge two datasets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can join them with a simple concat function.**

```
both_tables = pd.concat([report1, report2])

both_tables
```

#### Example

**First table**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
['1', 'Fares', 32, True],
['2', 'Elena', 23, False],
['3', 'Steven', 40, True]])

df1.columns = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'decision']

df1
```

[image]

**Second table**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
['4', 'Max', 24, True],
['5', 'Elena', 20, False],
['6', 'Steven', 40, True]])

df2.columns = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'decision']

df2
```

[image]

**Joining both tables togehter**

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df3
```

[image]

I hope I could help you out a bit.